# Does the space $E^3\times S^2$ have a name?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, euclidean-geometry, manifolds

Usually in robotics the task space is $E_+(3)$ ($E^3\times O_+(3)$). In robot welding, the robot is free to "roll" the tool around the welding wire, and hence the task space for the weld tool is $E^3\times S^2$. Another example where it arises is with point cloud sensors, where a surface is sampled by laser triangulation, and each point is annotated by the surface normal at that point. These surface points with normal direction is then also a set of elements of $E^3\times S^2$. Does this space have a commonly used name?

Comment: I am not aware of a special name, though it's not hard to write it in symbols, and if you're in a context where you need to work with it frequently, there is no harm in giving it a name (e.g., "position space"), although the robotics literature may already have a name.  However, I have not seen a particular name used by mathematicians.  Most spaces do not have names outside of symbols, though.